# On OS X, why the showimage example of SDL2_image needs to do RenderCopy() in the while loop?

Tags: macos, sdl-2

For quick reference, the showimage.c example code in SDL2_image library has the following code:

```
    /* Show the window */
    SDL_SetWindowTitle(window, argv[i]);
    SDL_SetWindowSize(window, w, h);
    SDL_ShowWindow(window);

    done = 0;
    while ( ! done ) {
        while ( SDL_PollEvent(&event) ) {
            /* some event handling code... */
        }
        /* Draw a background pattern in case the image has transparency */
        draw_background(renderer, w, h);

        /* Display the image */
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        SDL_Delay(100);
    }
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
}
```

`SDL_RenderCopy()` and `SDL_RenderPresent()` are called in the `while(!done)` block.

Since it only loads one image, I thought the texture should be created and rendered to frame buffer once and just left it there. So `SDL_RenderCopy()` and `SDL_RenderPresent()` should be called only once:

```
    /* Show the window */
    SDL_SetWindowTitle(window, argv[i]);
    SDL_SetWindowSize(window, w, h);
    SDL_ShowWindow(window);

    /* Draw a background pattern in case the image has transparency */
    draw_background(renderer, w, h);

    /* Display the image */
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    done = 0;
    while ( ! done ) {
        while ( SDL_PollEvent(&event) ) {
            /* some event handling code... */
        }

        SDL_Delay(100);
    }
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
}
```

On my ubuntu 12.04, the image was shown as my expectation. However, on my MBA with OSX 10.9.2, it was all black.

Why the difference?

Comment: It's possible this is an SDL 2.0 bug, or it's possible that your computer was not able to render the texture. You could try a simple test to be sure that it's rendering the image at all. I've had a bug with SDL 2.0 that made me have to render twice before the image was shown.

Comment: @user3476738 You're right. I duplicated the code from draw_backgroud() to SDL_RenderPresent() twice and the image was shown. I'm going to take some time inspecting SDL2 source code to see what's going on...thanks!

Comment: Sounds similar to a problem described in this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003676/sdl2-invalid-renderer-on-sdl-getwindowsurface-and-or-sdl-createrenderer-on-osx#comment38915181_25003676

Comment: Looks like the common thread here is MBA, hmm Intel HD 3000 in my case. Which do you have @southp?

Comment: @Keyframe Mine is Intel HD 4000. Four months passed and I didn't really inspect on SDL 2.0 source code, though :(

Comment: @southp I'll see if 2.0.4 solves the issue when it's out and if not I'll inspect the code in library itself then. No way around it I guess :/

Answer (score 0):

The example code is simply demonstrating the most portable way to render to the screen.  Your app doesn't necessarily control whether the OS uses double (or triple) buffering, so you can't rely on a single render being consistently presented to the user.  Also, there are potential situations where the default framebuffer contents can be lost/altered.

In other words, you *should* be rendering every frame.

Comment: Good point at the framebuffer consistency issue that I didn't think of.