# SDL2 Invalid renderer on SDL_GetWindowSurface and/or SDL_CreateRenderer on OSX

Tags: c, macos, sdl, sdl-2

So I've been playing around with SDL2 to see if it would suit my needs. I was following introductory examples (from lazyfoo mostly) and made a simple test.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    /* The window handle */
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    /* The surface contained in the window */
    SDL_Surface* screen_surface = NULL;

    /* Init SDL */
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        /* Create window */
        window = SDL_CreateWindow(
            "SDL Window", 
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
            SCREEN_WIDTH, 
            SCREEN_HEIGHT, 
            SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS
        );

        if(window == NULL) {
            printf("Window could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            // /* Get window surface */
            screen_surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

            // /* Fill the surface white */
            SDL_FillRect(screen_surface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screen_surface->format, 0x50, 0x50, 0x50));

            // /* Update the surface */
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

            printf("%s\n", SDL_GetError());

            /* Wait n secs */
            SDL_Delay(2000);

        }
    }

    /* Destroy the window */
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    /* Quit SDL subsystem */
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled on OSX 10.7.5 (MBA 2011) with:

```
gcc `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -o sdl_test sdl_test.c
```

Example is simple enough. It should init SDL, create a window, attach a surface to the window, set the color to gray and render it out - after two seconds it should exit.

However, window stays black. No gray surface shown. That's why I introduced that printf for SDL errors before delay. It shows `Invalid renderer` which I have tracked down to be triggered by `screen_surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);`

I have also tried to do it the other way with

```
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

instead of SDL_Surface way.. but same thing happens `Invalid renderer` thrown out on SDL_CreateRenderer. As you can see, I tried it with _SOFTWARE and _ACCELERATED flags - same thing.

Now, here's the 'funny' part. In first code, with SDL_Surface way I have called SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window); twice - one after the other. Gray color shows! However, `Invalid renderer` is still thrown out, but code works. Why would calling `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);` twice, one after the other, work and once it wouldn't? Why would it work at all if `Invalid renderer` is thrown out? I'm deeply puzzled.

- **OSX:** 10.7.5
- **compiler:** i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
- **SDL2:** 2.0.3 (installed via homebrew)

I also tried invoking gcc without sdl2-config by manually typing include path and libs.

Comment: The code is sound. I have just tested on both Windows 7 (VS2013) and OSX (Mav, XCode 5.1.1) and it displayed a gray coloured window for 2 seconds as expected.

Comment: Thanks for testing! I was afraid something like that might happen. I have to figure out where to start debugging this issue from. It's baffling.

Comment: Might be worth registering on the forums at the SDL site and asking there to see if anyone has had the same issue. Sam, the main developer often replies to threads on there too - https://forums.libsdl.org/

Comment: Seems like it might be a bug - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801113/on-os-x-why-the-showimage-example-of-sdl2-image-needs-to-do-rendercopy-in-the

Comment: @Zammalad seems like it. I registered on SDL forum, but I can't post anything there. This must be a bug only because I tried to have a go at SDL2.

Comment: see this post about how to make posts on SDL forums - https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=9845